# django form submission error (passing parameter from view.py to form)

Tags: python, django, forms, postgresql, parameters

I am a beginner to Django and Postgresql, and new to stackoverflow. Currently I am developing a web app that allows the user to create a new postgresql database, as well as connect to a existing database through webpage.

I successfully implemented the createdb function, however has encountered some issue when implementing the selectdb function. The problem is when the second time it enters the selectdb (after user has selected a database and submit the result), the form.is_valid() always return false.

I want to create a dynamic django form since the number of databases are not fixed. So i want to pass in parameters from view.py to the selectdb_form.py file The form has a drop down field where lists all the database name that can be selected by the user.

This is the error returned after i click submit:

```
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'my_arg'
Exception Location: /Users/jetyue/Documents/atdb-web/smem02_webapp/webapp/selectdb_form.py in __init__, line 5
```

this is the function inside view.py (please ignore the bad indentation here, it is correct in my file). 
I also noticed this wired output from print request.POST:

```
<QueryDict: {u'SelectDatabase': [u'3'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'HxtAofaKD9FiSLLWk3vkbAdIh0mCUhdJ'], u'submit': [u'Connect to Database']}>
```

I do not know where does the u' come from.

```
def selectdb (request):
    final_name = []

    if request.method == 'POST': #if form is submitted, comes in here
        print request.POST
        form = selectdb_form(request.POST)
        print "inside post first if"

        if form.is_valid():
            print "inside post second if"

            dataBase_name = form.cleaned_data['SelectDatabase']
            print dataBase_name + "========"

            #select a postgresql database 
            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='"+dataBase_name+"' user='jet' host='localhost' password='jet' port='5432' ")

            args_done = {}
            args_done.update(csrf(request))

            args_done['dataBase_name'] = dataBase_name
            return render_to_response('selectdb_done.html', args_done)


        #return render_to_response('main.html')

    else:

        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='jet' host='localhost' password='jet' port='5432' ")

        #conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        names = []
        cur.execute('SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false ORDER BY datname;')
        names = cur.fetchall()

        #print names
        num = 0;
        while num< len(names):
            #print names[num]
            clean_name = names[num][0]
            #print clean_name
            tuple_name = (num+1, clean_name)
            final_name.append(tuple_name)
            num += 1;   

        #print final_name

        cur.close()
        conn.close()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    form = selectdb_form(my_arg = final_name)

    args['form'] = form
    #print args
    return render_to_response('selectdb.html', args)
```

This is the dynamic form (selectdb_form.py) file:

```
from django import forms

class selectdb_form(forms.Form):
    def  __init__(self,  *args,  **kwargs):
        my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg') 
        super(selectdb_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['SelectDatabase'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=my_arg, widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
```

I wonder if there is anything wrong with my dynamic form? I mean can i use  `form = selectdb_form(request.POST)` with the dynamic form? since that's where the error occurs.

Thank you guys so much for helping me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly instantiate the form twice, once in the GET block and once in the POST. However, you only pass the `my_arg` argument in the GET block. Since your `__init__` method requires that argument, you get an error. You should make sure to pass the argument both times.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Roseman for the reply! I tried this similar method:  `form = selectdb_form(request.POST, myarg = final_name)` in the POST part before, but it didnt work for me. (it keeps on adding the /webapp/selectdb part to the url like this: http://localhost:8000/webapp/selectdb/webapp/selectdb/webapp/selectdb/) All I want is to get the data submitted in the forms.ChoiceField in the POST part. I wonder is there any simple solution to this? Big thanks!!

Comment: Thanks! i fixed the problem: the second time when i entered seledtdb (post part), final_name was empty, so nothing was passed into my_arg, i ended up connect to the postgresql db and get the names again and set it inside final_name.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that there is no key word argument called `my_arg` in `kwargs`.

You might want to check if `my_arg` is present or not using `if 'my_arg' in kwargs:`

Finally the `u` means your data is in `unicode`. Wont cause any problem i guess.